# Access denied on Windows Forms Application fetching process.startTime

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am trying to print Windows all processes names, startTime and EndTime.

```
private void loadProcessList()
{
    label1.Visible = false;
    listView1.Items.Clear();
    Process[] processList = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (Process process in processList)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(process.ProcessName);
        item.Tag = process;
        DateTime started = process.StartTime;
        string[] row1 = { "Running", started.ToString(), "00:00" };
        listView1.Items.Add(item).SubItems.AddRange(row1);
       }
    }
```

process.ProcessName is working fine. But when I try to fetch the process startTime or EndTime I get this error:

[image: ErrorMessage]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you make sure that the user has the [PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880(v=vs.85).aspx) access right, that should be enough to fix the Access denied exception. However, if you don't have control over the access rights, you should try to use [WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx) (Windows Management Instrumentation) to get the process information.

You basically use a query language to get the information you want from the processes running on the computer. Here's an example of how to use it:

[Process Information and Notifications using WMI](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12138/Process-Information-and-Notifications-using-WMI)

The article is pretty old but WMI still works the same way in newer versions of Windows. You might still need to do modifications but in the best case, the code will work for you as it is.

Comment: i already tried WMI and i have getting ManagementScope does not exist in the namespace error

Comment: @Coder47 Do you have a reference to System.Management in your project? That's where the ManagementScope class is.

Comment: yes, i have System.Management but system is not using that